# Textview on(above) Button, doesn't work in Android 5(API 21)

Tags: android, position

It looks like a bug in 5 Android(API 21). I need a textview on button, textview should placed above the button. It works correct on Android 4.1(API 16) and incorrect on 5 Android(API 21). There are Screenshots and code:

Android 4.1 - It is correct, red textview above the button

[image: Android 4.1]

Android 5 - it is **incorrect**, red textview under the button!

[image: Android 5]

Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/rlBottom"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >



<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="#00FF00">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bVio"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:text="VIO"></Button>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bVio_count"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="00"
        android:textSize="12dip"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_textbox"/>

    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

rounded_textbox - it is just shape... if remove background, all looks same, textview under button in 5 android.

Please, advice!

Comment: http://bit.ly/1xYcyuy  here is another screenshot API 20 and API 21 - So error is only in Android 5

Comment: Their seems to be [bringToFront()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#bringToFront()) for a `View`. You can try it.

Comment: also doesn't work, I tried it.

Comment: What hapens when you remove `android:background="#00FF00"` from `FrameLayout` just for the time being ?

Comment: Buttons have elevation by default and will be z-ordered accordingly.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Yes. It is big chnage in Android L(API 21). There is new thing - Elevation, it is something like z-index in HTML. So to fix this bug you need use android:elevation="100dp" OR android:translationZ="100dip"  for view that should be on top.  So correct code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/rlBottom"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >



<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="#00FF00">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bVio"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:text="VIO"></Button>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bVio_count"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="00"
        android:textSize="12dip"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_textbox"
        android:elevation="100dp"/>

    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: android:translationZ="100dip" is not working and value of elevation can be anything greater than "1dp" (e.g.: android:elevation="2dp").

Comment: Making elevation 2dp is a silly idea since in pressed state elevation is greater thus the TextView fill go under the button

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your button in a layout separately from the `TextView`, I used `FrameLayout` to wrap it and make sure your `TextView` is under the button's layout and it should work.