# TextView hidden by previous View in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, view

My issue is simple I have a basic layout with two views with two custom drawables as background, here is the code :

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relaunch_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:layout_above="@+id/playLayout">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/relaunch"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Relancer"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:textColor="#FFF0951C"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_button"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nbspins_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="6dp"
        android:paddingRight="6dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="-10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/circular_shape"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/relaunch" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And the shape for my Views :

Button shape :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="15dp" />
            <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#FFF0951C" />
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

TextView shape :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#FF0000" />
    <corners
        android:topLeftRadius="15dp"
        android:topRightRadius="15dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="15dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="15dp"
    />
</shape>
```

I can't figure out why, my TextView is not displayed above my Button, here is the result I get :

[image]

The result I want :

[image]

Can you see why ?

Comment: Try adding `android:layout_below="@id=relaunch"`. Errr...what do you mean by "after my Button"? Below or to the right of it?

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to say above ! I made the correction

Comment: Probably a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27134400/textview-onabove-button-doesnt-work-in-android-5api-21

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I know what you mean.

The button uses the following:

```
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
```

so is aligning with the top of the `RelativeLayout`.

Remove that and change it to

android:layout_below="@id=nbspins_view"

and make the `TextView` align with the parent top.

Comment: If I make this, my button is just below my textview. I added an image to be more clear about the result I want

Comment: oh ok. Then just use a `FrameLayout` instead of a `RelativeLayout`. Items appear on top in the order that they're placed in the XML.

Comment: @eoinzy What api are you targeting ? It could be a elevation issue with android >5 try set elevation of your textview to a high number (above default button elevation), else replace button with a simple textview with padding etc. just to debug whats the problem